# Polygon divided to Triangles (Cycles)

Tags: modeling, rendering

How can I achieve flat poly surfaces without the render dividing it into triangles?

In Object Mode and Eevee it looks ok, but not when rendered in Cycles.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **Technically, every render engine divides all the quads into triangles - no exceptions.** You can mask it with shading, but you can't prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that cycles decided to show a triangle instead of a quad because the vertex of that quad are not aligned. You can flatten the face of that quad by selecting it and pressing <kbd>W</kbd>  *>Loop tool > Flatten*

[image]

It seems normal on the view port but show tri on cycles render

[image]

If you don't have that option, simply activate it in the add-ons preferences (next picture)

[image]

Hit <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to access the preferences and type *loop* in the add-ons section.

[image]

The vertex are now aligned and there is no more tri (but the shape did change a little)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use shade smooth to get a similar effect in cycles:

Select the polygon-face, and do *Face* -> *shade smooth*

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question. Where's the render result from Cycles?

Comment: This is shown in the rendered view (with cycles,  when in edit mode) I chose this view to show that there is no geometry change between both, while only the first one shows the theoretical edge. The cycles rendered view matches the result of a render in cycles.